# Turn off alert message in Devise Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, alert

I'm using Devise for my Rails 3 app.

How do I turn off Devise's alert messages for sign on/off successfully?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can either:

1. Go to config\locales\devise.en.yml and change the lines you want to empty strings (deleting them won't work). So, like this:

   ```
   sessions:
     signed_in: ''
     signed_out: ''
   ```
2. Or extend/override devise's sessions controller. To do this, copy the `create` and `destroy` actions code from [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/sessions_controller.rb), and paste it in a controller (let's call it sessions) that inherits from devise's sessions controller, like this:

   ```
   class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
   ```

   Then remove the calls to set_flash_message. Finally, edit your routes file so this change takes effect:

   ```
   devise_for :users, :controllers => { :sessions => 'sessions' }
   ```

Comment: In Rails 4 and Devise 3.4+ you want config/locales/en.yml (remember to add en: and devise: to the scope).

Comment: Works perfectly!  I had no idea you could make the translation a blank screen and it would suppress a single flash notice!

Comment: Doesn't work for me. It shows an empty alert. :( Also, I'm trying to suppress the "already sign in" message.

Answer (score 0):

Building on what others said, this way might be a little easier than having to extend devise or anything like that.

Make sure to use empty strings instead of removing the whole line, otherwise devise will just go back to using the default value for that message.

```
# blank out any string you don't want to render as a message
devise:
  failure:
    already_authenticated: ''
    unauthenticated: ''
    unconfirmed: ''
   ...
```

Now devise will still pass the empty string as a flash alert. But now it will look something like this with the message being an empty string

```
#<ActionDispatch::Flash::FlashHash:0xa7647c4
  @closed=false,
  @flashes={:alert=>""},
  @now=nil,
  @used=#<Set: {:alert}>>
```

I use a helper method in my ApplicationHelper file that handles collecting all the messages together. You may do this differently, but this will give you the idea.

```
def all_messages

  # Standard flash messages
  messages = flash.map{|key,val| {:type=>key, :message=>val} unless val.blank? }.compact
    #                                                        |-------------------------|
    # This is where the magic happens. This is how I ignore any blank messages

  # Model validation errors
  model = instance_variable_get("@#{controller_name.singularize}")
  unless model.nil?
    messages += model.errors.full_messages.map do |msg|
      {:type=>:error, :message=>msg}
    end
  end

  return messages

end
```

And voila, the `unless val.blank?` statement maps any blank value to nil, and the `.compact` method will remove any nil values, leaving you with a squeaky clean array with no blank messages.